# How to parse a JSON with trailing and starting text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am looking to create an HTML version of a JSON, through JavaScript(jQuery), specifically the unofficial Google Dictionary JSON (http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html).

The problem I am facing is that the JSON is not readable because it has this in front of it "`dict_api.callbacks.id100(`" and is trailed by "`,200,null)`".

How can I remove this and then put it into a JSON object such that I can attach the elements to the HTML.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting the value from a string? and are those two parts always the same or do they ever change?

Comment: according to the linked blog-post, that api is not intended for general consumption, due to the licence under which google operates that dataset; that resource is likely to go away. Are you sure you want to use it anyway?

Comment: Im just using it as a project for school nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JSONP response.

It calls a function specified by the `callback` parameter to give you the response.
You should create a global function to handle the response, and pass its name as the `callback`.

jQuery will do this for you:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?q=test&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te&callback=?",
    function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
)
```

Comment: this for some odd reason it gives a blank Json.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is write a regular expression (or a pair of them) to do something like:

string.replace(/Regular expression that matches start/, "")
string.replace(/Regulat expression that matches the finish/, "")

Be careful not to use greedy regular expressions if you go this route, I have seen entertaining-but-not-very-helpful results with greed exressions in cases like this.

Otherwise, I would definitely go with the other response by SLaks related to using JQuery, as it should also give you additonal abilities to work with the data later, should your need change after the fact.